# the INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint when using frontend, but works when using Postman?

Tags: sql-server, angular, api, .net-core, frontend

I'm making an Angular (frontend) project (Visual Studio Code) with a .NET Core backend (Visual Studio). My backend works **perfectly** when I test it with Postman.

I have an API call to post a 'dier' and it works with Postman (AND when I try it with Swagger), but when I use my frontend in Angular I get a **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException** saying

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"GebruikerID\". The conflict occurred in database \"master\", table
>   \"dbo.Gebruiker\", column 'GebruikerID'.\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."

My backend expects a JSON like this:

```
 {
  "naam": "string",
  "soort": "string",
  "gebruikerID": 0
}
```

My model in angular (without imports):

```
export interface DierJson{
    id: number;
    naam: string;
    soort: string;
    gebruikerID: number;
}

export class Dier{
    private _id: number;
    constructor(

        private _naam: string,
        private _soort: string,
        private _gebruikerid: number
      ) {}

      get id(): number {
        return this._id;
      }
      get naam(): string {
        return this._naam;
      }
      get soort(): string {
        return this._soort;
      }
      get gebruikerid(): number {
        return this._id;
      }



      static fromJSON(json: DierJson): Dier {
        const dier = new Dier(json.naam, json.soort, json.gebruikerID);
        dier._id = json.id;
        return dier;
      }

    toJSON(): DierJson {
        return <DierJson>{
          naam: this.naam,
          soort: this.soort,
          gebruikerID: this.gebruikerid
        };
    }
}
```

The submit button method in my component:

```
onSubmit(){
    this._dierdataservice
    .addNewDier(new Dier(this.dier.value.naam, this.dier.value.soort, 1)) //THE 1 IS HARDCODED FOR NOW
    .pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        this.errorMessage = err;
        return EMPTY;
      })
    )
    .subscribe((rec: Dier) => {
      this.confirmationMessage = `Het dier ${rec.naam} is toegevoegd`;
    });

    //rebind to a new group here after a submit (so the form resets)
    this.dier = this.fb.group({
      naam: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      soort: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]]
    });
  }
```

And the method in the Dataservice:

```
addNewDier(dier: Dier) {
    return this.http
    .post(`${environment.apiUrl}/Dieren`, dier.toJSON())
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError), map(Dier.fromJSON))
    .pipe(
      // temporary fix, while we use the behaviorsubject as a cache stream
      catchError((err) => {
        this._dieren$.error(err);
        return throwError(err);
      }),
      tap((rec: Dier) => {
        this._dieren = [...this._dieren, rec];
        this._dieren$.next(this._dieren);
      })
    );
  }
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: open devTools in your browser and compare what is sent to backend with what you send via postman and you will see what is causing the exception.

Comment: @YuriyKravets That's how I found it! Thank you! It should have been `get gebruikerid(): number {
        return this._gebruikerid;
      }`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to temporary remove foreign key between table dbo.Gebruiker.
Run this in SSMS:

```
USE master
GO
DROP CONSTRAINT GebruikerID ON [dbo].[target table]
```

Then run the post from frontend and check the new row in your target table. You will see what is the problem.